# Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http utf-8

Tags: zend-framework, utf-8

I'm using Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http to upload file to my server.
There is a bug when I upload file with accents in their name. The file is uplaoded but there are strange chars instead of the accentuated ones.

Do you guys have a clue ?

Regards,

Comment: Could you copy/paste your code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to rename my files for security purposes. This way I don't encounter this problem anymore.

```
if(!file_exists($path))
        mkdir($path);

    $upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
    $upload->setDestination($path);

    try {
        $info = $upload->getFileInfo();
        $filename = $info[$input_name]['name'];

        if ($upload->isValid()) {   
            $file_array = explode('.', $info[$input_name]['name'], 2);
            $new_filename = rand().'.'. $file_array[1];
            $upload->addFilter('Rename', $new_filename);                 
            $upload->receive();
        }
```